# Firebase Authentication with Google Identity (GoogleYOLO)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

Is it possible to combine Google Identity (GoogleYOLO) with the Firebase Authentication web stack? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: FirebaseUI generally implements all the patterns if you want examples: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI  - can you say a little more about what features you were looking to integrate though (in general: everything can work!)

Comment: Sure. My application utilizes a custom Firebase authentication system instead of the firebase UI. I utiilize the current sign in with Google, however would like the user to be able to login without going to say a sign up page. However, I would wish to know how to connect the firebase auth backend with Google YOLO (how do we save auth?)

For example: I can utilize firebase.auth.signInWithGoogle() to sign in with google on the click of a button and firebase auth will save and handle the data passthrough with the backend. Can this be done with Google YOLO?

Comment: Hey Brandon, is this for Android or Web?

Comment: @bojeil This is for web (firebase-js)

Comment: As mentioned by Ian, you should check out FirebaseUI-web which already integrates with one-tap sign-up and auto sign-in: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#one-tap-sign-up

Comment: So this is not possible with a custom firebase authentication system that does not work with FirebaseUI? By simply utilizing the base firebase auth package?

Comment: Your question was too vague. It is possible. Check response below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can sign in with googleyolo using Firebase Auth as follows:

```
hintPromise.then((credential) => {
  if (credential.idToken) {
    // Initialize firebase Auth credential with Google ID token
    // obtained from googleyolo.
    const cred = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(credential.idToken);
    // Sign in with
    return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred);
  }
  throw new Error;
}).then((result) => {
  // User signed in.
}).catch((error) => {
  // Handle error.
});
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much @bojeil! I was thinking that it had to be done with something with `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider`, but I did not know I had to utilize the `signInWithCredential`

Answer (score 0):

Building on @bojeil's reply, the ID token required by Firebase's `signInWithCredential` function exists within the `credential` property of the `credential` object. Therefore, rather than retrieving the token using `credential.idToken`, you must retrieve the token with `credential.credential`. Here is a sample function below using Firebase V8.

```js
// firebase V8
function handleCredentialResponse(credential) {
  if (credential) {
    const cred = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(credential.credential);

    // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
    return auth().signInWithCredential(cred);
  }
}
```

The `credential` param is a credential response returned from the Google one-tap function callback.

```js
 google?.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: your-google-app-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com,
    callback: handleCredentialResponse,
 });
 google?.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
    console.log(notification);
 });
```